# Searchlogic: Strange behaviour when combining scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, searchlogic

I'm currently implementing a search form in our users database. I would like to search by id , by login or by email.

Naturally, I think that the best aproach is to combine scopes and simplify the form. So I added a text_field for `:id_or_login_or_email_like`.

Everything works fine when I type a number in the text-field.

However, when I type a word and press search, the value i typed is losed and replaced with a 0 (zero) and the search result returns all users that have 0 in the ID, name or login.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using Rails 2.3.2 and SearchLogic 2.4.27.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found a workaround: when combining scopes with OR, put the scope related to integer values at the end.

So instead of `:id_or_login_or_email_like` use `login_or_email_or_id_like`. I've submitted this issue via [github](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/issues/issue/140/).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your scope is making a comparison against an integer when comparing to id, which causes your string to be converted to 0.  Try using .dup to ensure that the passed attribute to the scope is not changed.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds more like an issue with the gem. I really do not want to ge in that direction. I'll submit your sugestion to the author of the gem :)